Avoid woocommerce_thankyou hook to be trigerred multiple times or on old orders
I'm using the woocommerce_thankyou hook in my WooCommerce site to send order data to an external URL via a POST request whenever a new order is created. However, I've noticed that this hook is sometimes triggering on very old orders, causing unexpected POST requests. Here's the code I'm using:
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_external_url', 10, 1);
    
function send_order_to_external_url($order_id) {
    if (!$order_id) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the order details
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Prepare the data to send
    $data = array(
        'order_id'      => $order_id,
        'order_total'   => $order->get_total(),
        'billing_email' => $order->get_billing_email(),
        'billing_phone' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
        // Add other necessary order details here
    );

    // Convert data to JSON
    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    // The endpoint URL
    $url = 'https://example.com/your-endpoint';

    // Send the data via wp_remote_post
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => $json_data,
        'headers'   => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
    ));

    // Check for errors (optional)
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        error_log('Error sending order data: ' . $error_message);
    }
}

My questions are:

Why might the woocommerce_thankyou hook be triggering on old orders?
How can I prevent this hook from triggering on anything but newly created orders?

Any insights or suggestions to debug and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Each time a customer browse the Order received (thankyou) page, your function code is executed… So for example, a customer can keep the Order received (thankyou) URL related to one of his orders, and browse it again another day, later.
So to avoid your issue you can:

force the code to be executed only once per order,
avoid orders with a creation date older than 3 days (for example).

Try the following replacement code:
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_external_url', 10, 1);
    
function send_order_to_external_url($order_id) {
    if (!$order_id) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the order details
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Exit if thankyou page has been already viewed
    if ( $order->get_meta('_thankyou_viewed') ) {
        return;
    }

    // Exit if the order creation date is older than "3 days"
    if ( strtotime($order->get_date_created()) < strtotime('- 3 days') ) {
        return;
    }

    // Prepare the data to send
    $data = array(
        'order_id'      => $order_id,
        'order_total'   => $order->get_total(),
        'billing_email' => $order->get_billing_email(),
        'billing_phone' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
        // Add other necessary order details here
    );

    // Convert data to JSON
    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    // The endpoint URL
    $url = 'https://example.com/your-endpoint';

    // Send the data via wp_remote_post
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => $json_data,
        'headers'   => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
    ));

    // Check for errors (optional)
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        error_log('Error sending order data: ' . $error_message);
    }

    // Tag the order as "thankyou" viewed (add custom metadata)
    $order->update_meta_data('_thankyou_viewed', true);
    $order->save();
}

It should work as before, but avoiding the issue you describe.
You can change easily the allowed number of days related to the date creation.

It doesn't make sense to display the thank you page again for an order that was created months ago. Do you think there could be something else triggering this? I can do what you said, but if something triggers the "thank you page", then setting a time limit like "3 days ago" or "1 day ago" will not be a solution. Maybe it will trigger again an order that came 45 minutes ago. I can add a metadata to each order when the thank you page is displayed, but in this case, there will still be a problem because very old orders do not have this data.
